# return 500 status code using HTTPAdapter

Tags: http, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have an orchestration with request-response receive port with HTTP adapter. If an exception occurs in the orchestration the HTTP adapter still returns 200 status.

Is it possible to make the HTTP adapter returns a 500 status error instead of 200?

My BizTalk version is 2010.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better practice to return a message to the caller which includes an optional error node in which you raise it as a business exception.

Quite a few systems will automatically retry the message if they get a 500 status in which case it will just keep failing.

If you reject the message at a business level it is then a matter of working out if the message should have been accepted (in which case you need to fix your code) or if the sender has a mistake (in which case they need to fix what they are sending).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done through the HTTP adapter, but you could definitely achieve it with a WCF-Custom adapter.  Unfortunately, BTS 2010 doesn't provide easy access to the WebHttp binding, but you could achieve that with the WCF-Custom, or if you want to do SOAP you could use WCF-BasicHttp.  Sending a message back on a fault port should generate a 500 code.

Just keep in mind that to achieve that you'd have to allow fault messages to be routed to the caller, and you'd probably want to have a custom WCF-Behavior to scrub the message to remove sensitive details that might be transmitted over a fault port (such as stack trace information).